# Custom voice for TextToSpeech Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Is there any possibility to set custom voice for TTS like baby girl voice?

I have tried getVoices() like following,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    Set<Locale> localeSet = tts.getAvailableLanguages();
    for (Locale locale : localeSet) {
        Log.v(TAG, locale.getDisplayName() + " - " + locale.getDisplayLanguage() + " - " + locale.getCountry());
        if (locale.getDisplayLanguage().equals("Tamil")) {
            result = tts.setLanguage(locale);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                tts.setSpeechRate(0.05f);
                //tts.setPitch(5.0f);
                fabSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }
        }
    }

    Set<Voice> voices = tts.getVoices();
    for (Voice voice : voices) {
        Log.v(TAG, voice.getName());
        if (voice.getName().equals("hi-in-x-cfn#female_2-local")) {
            tts.setVoice(voice);
        }
    }
}
```

But this voice replaced language, So this code doesn't read Tamil anymore. If I comment the `setVoice()` then it read Tamil with default male voice.

I want this given text to be read by this female voice. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This scenario occurs because by default every Voice has a Locale value that overrides Locale value you set on your function. I think you can override this by creating a new Voice instance that features same set as your desired one by overriding Locale attribute in your for loop as such:

```
for (Voice voice: voices) {
 Log.v(TAG, voice.getName());
 if (voice.getName().equals("hi-in-x-cfn#female_2-local")) {
  tts.setVoice(new Voice(voice.getName(),
   locale, // YOUR LOCALE GOES HERE
   voice.getQuality(),
   voice.getLatency(),
   voice.isNetworkConnectionRequired(),
   voice.getFeatures()));
 }
}
```

Comment: seems doubtful.